# Can we never have a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution

Since the population variance can never be estimated, will we always have a t-distribution instead of normal?

Comment: Please clarify this question: What setting do you have in mind where we cannot estimate a population variance?

Comment: I think it should also say that from a practical point of view the population variance can never be estimated.

Comment: This is what I intended

Comment: Since the t-distribution relies on normality and we don't have actual normal populations, in practice we never really have t-distributions either.

Comment: Could you explain that more?

Comment: Sure - but if you don't say "@Glen_b" in your response, I won't see your request (unless I am lucky enough to stumble on it as I happened to in this case). The derivation of the distribution of the $t$ statistic relies on the numerator being normal. If we don't have normality in the first place, the derivation of the $t$ that relies on it doesn't go through.

Comment: The population variance can be estimated and the estimate is used in the calculation of the t statistic.  I think the OP means that the population variance for all practical purposes is unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @whuber essentially points out, I believe your question is "Since the population variance can never be ***known***, will we always have a t-distribution instead of normal?" - not "estimated".

Who said that the population variance is never known? First, it depends on whether you have a sample, or the whole population (there are cases where you may have the whole population available). Also, it depends on whether your data is experimental or not. Think of the oldest example -with a twist: suppose you investigate the flipping of two coins separately. The coins are not fair, but they tell you that they are biased so as both to have variance, say, $\frac16$ (=experimental data). Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$, each associated with one of the coins. Each takes the value 1 if heads comes up, zero if tails comes up. You have to investigate whether the two random variables have the same mean, given two independent samples of flippings from each coin. Your tests will be run with known population variances.

(PS: I take it you realize that excpet when the variance is $\frac 14$ (i.e coin is fair), knowing the variance does not give a unique solution for the mean).

Comment: Yeah sorry for framing it wrong. This is what I intended